# Sylius - Shop Api - when shop API runs error occurred Unable to find template ""

Tags: php, api, symfony, sylius

Im trying to use the sylius [shop-api](https://github.com/Sylius/ShopApiPlugin) plugging and following thi [DOC](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/Sylius/sylius-shop-api/1.0.0#/) as API doc.
I successfully installed the plugging and I tried to run a GET method as first time
( `http://localhost:8000/shop-api/product-latest?locale=en_US&limit=10` )

It's showing a error as bellow

```
Unable to find template "" (looked into: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php/arimac-ecommerce/vendor/knplabs/knp-menu/src/Knp/Menu/Resources/views, /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php/arimac-ecommerce/templates, /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php/arimac-ecommerce/templates, /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php/arimac-ecommerce/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form).
```

[image]
Please guide me to resolve this error

Answer (score 2):

This error occurred due to the **priority** of the rule that define in the **fos_rest** ( `config/packages/fos_rest.yaml` )

[image]

once you fix the rule priority **clear the cash** and run the curl. Then you will get the result as you expected

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Set the following HTTP request headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```